# How to generate multiple packages with Rake?

Tags: ruby, rake

The task i'm using looks something like this:

```
Rake::PackageTask.new("deploy", "0.1.2") do |p|
  p.need_tar = true
  p.package_files.include("build/**/*")
end
```

This generates a `deploy-0.1.2.zip` file. I would like to be able to generate a different package for each folder contained in the build, for example:

```
build/
  |— en/
  |— es/
  |— de/
  |— fr/
```

Should generate `deploy-en-0.1.2.zip`, `deploy-es-0.1.2.zip`, `deploy-de-0.1.2.zip`, `deploy-fr-0.1.2.zip` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preconised concept is to locales, not make specific packages
Work with i18n, create a determining code if needed or assuming the locales of the workstation, server how code is executed (in case of CLI, library, etc...)

Otherwise you could create n clones for each languages of your project and create a Rakefile in the root folder how do explicit or recursive call of rake target for each gem building...
you need to do n specific gemspec (one for a specific language) , you also need to write a opy target in your Rakefile to centralized packages because of the differents pkg folders build in each language specific gem folder you create? 
Personnaly i think it's not a good idea, you have to maintained n similar copy of the same application ....

Comment: Thank you for the input Romain. My question goes behind locales, I just mention it as an example, the question is how to generate multiple packages with rake. Maybe I should clarify that in the description.

Comment: it's the end of my explanation, you have to create multiple gemspec ans iterate over in a top level Rakefile => a rake who call explicitly or recursively other Rakefile or Gemspec files.